# ZK: loading value/text into selectbox

Tags: zk

I have a `selectbox` and want to load the value and text into the template, similar to an HTML dropdown box. I am using ZK framework with Java on the back end.

```
<selectbox id="buListbox" model="${$composer.buModel}" >
  <template name="model">
    <label value="${each}" />
  </template>
</selectbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using ZK, you don't need the value to identify the selected object like in HTML.

When using the MVC pattern, binding a model via `model` attribute, the selected item is also stored in that model and can be retrieved in java via `model.getSelection()`.
Furthermore, a model is not restricted to lists of `String`, but it can hold any object type you want. In the `template` section, you can display any property of that object. Then the properties' `toString()` method is used to get the value which is displayed. This also applies to `${each}` itself.

Example:

Assuming your model is a `ListModelList` of type `ValueType`:

```
public class ValueType {
      private String value;
      private String text;

    public ValueType(String value, String text) {
      this.value=value;
      this.text=text;
    }

    public String getText() {
      return this.text;
    }

    public String getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }
  }

private ListModelList<ValueType> typesModel;

public ListModelList<ValueType> getTypesModel() {
   return typesModel;
}
```

You than can use the `selectbox`'s model/template to display it's text property:

```
<selectbox id="typesSelectbox" model="${$composer.typesModel}">
      <template name="model">
           ${each.text}
      </template>
</selectbox>
```

In java, you then get the selected item via `typeModel.getSelection()` .

[Here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/266s6gs/3-SO-Quesetion-3383439) you can find a working ZKFiddle example.